# How can I add more columns in VLC playlist?

Tags: vlc-media-player

I would like to see some additional columns and content like "AlbumArtist" or "AlbumArtistSort" in the playlist of VLC.
These aren't in the existing list of possible columns.

[image]

How can I add them?

Which setting do we have to modify? Or is there a LUA file that we can adjust?